# phonegap android app does not show my app icon :(

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I am working on an android app with phonegap. I have tried all sorts of stuff to get my icon on the app, but have been unsuccessful. The android bot icon appears on the app when installed from apk.

I have this in config.xml:

```
<icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/ldpi.png" />
<icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/mdpi.png" />
<icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/hdpi.png" />
<icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" />
<icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" />
```

I read http://devgirl.org/2013/09/12/phonegap-icons-and-splash-screens-help/
and the steps given here are already happening.

In my /platforms/android/res/ the desired icons and screens appear in the right drawable folder.

I dont know what i am doing wrong. cant just get the icon to show up.

I am not using the phonegap desktop app

Comment: Are you using [*Phonegap Desktop App*](http://phonegap.com/getstarted/)? If so, please add that information to your original message.

Comment: not using the desktop app

Comment: You have both *Phonegap Build* and *Phonegap CLI* listed in your tags. They are not the same. They do not work the same way. Why do you have both tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same filename (`ic_launcher.png` is the default and most common one) for all icons, while they are in different folders, and change your icons call in the `config.xml` file to this:

```
<icon src="folder-hdpi/ic_launcher.png"
    gap:platform="android"
    gap:density="hdpi"/>
<icon src="folder-mdpi/ic_launcher.png"
    gap:platform="android"
    gap:density="mdpi"/>
<icon src="folder-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png"
    gap:platform="android"
    gap:density="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="folder-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"
    gap:platform="android"
    gap:density="xxhdpi"/>
<icon src="folder-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"
    gap:platform="android"
    gap:density="xxxhdpi"/>
```